# How to reference a directory in my repo during a GitHub action build?

Tags: python, github, pytest, code-coverage, github-actions

I have some test data that I use for unit tests with pytest. I set their location with environment variables. Looking at my pytest logs the build sees the environment vars but the locations they reference don't exist. In the GitHub Actions docs the repo should be in /home/runner/Repo/. Below is my folder structure. Anyone see any obvious issues?

```
Repo/
  notebooks/
  repo/
    __init__.py
    tests/
      tests_db.hdf5
      Sample_Raw/
        ...
      __init__.py
      test_obj1.py
      test_obj2.py
    obj1.py
    obj2.py
    utils.py
```

build yaml

```
name: build-test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*' # all branches for now

jobs:
  build-and-run:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        python-version: [3.8]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Generate coverage report
      env:
        DB_URL: /home/runner/work/Repo/repo/tests/test_db.hdf5
        RAW_FOLDER: /home/runner/work/Repo/repo/tests/Sample_Raw/
      run: |
        pip install pytest
        pip install pytest-cov
        pytest --cov=./ --cov-report=xml
    - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        file: ./coverage.xml
        name: codecov-umbrella
```

Comment: try omitting the `/home/runner/work/Repo` part of your paths and just go with the relative path within the repo - I think the checkout action automatically `cd`s into the repo. Let me know if this works and I can make it an answer.

Comment: `DB_URL: ${{ github.workspace }}/repo/tests/test_db.hdf5` etc.

Comment: Also, AFAIK the checkout action uses smth like `/home/runner/work/<gh-user>/<gh-repo>` as workdir, may be wrong though.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: @Sam yes, hoefling's answer is what worked

Comment: As mentioned by MLarvrentyev, just use the relative path. So, try ./repo/tests/test_db.hdf5

Answer (score 3):

There are wellknown variables that you can use to ensure your workflow can always find the correct folder, no matter what runner it runs on.

The repository root can be found in `${{ github.workspace }}`:

```
DB_URL: ${{ github.workspace }}/repo/tests/test_db.hdf5
```

See:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts